# Windows Terminal behaves strangely in WSL2 when entering or leaving full-screen apps like man, vim, less

Tags: terminal, windows-terminal

I installed WLS2 Ubuntu on Windows 10.

I launch WSL in **Windows Terminal** and then:

```
type 'man man' to enter manpage
press 'd' to scroll down
press 'q' to quit
```

Everything looks fine at this point:

[image: Before screenshot]

... but when scroll up, the 'ghost' output shows up:

[image: Screenshot after scrolling up]

If launch WSL and do the same thing in **cmd**, everything's fine.

I noticed that in full-screen apps like `man`, `vim`, and `less'` **cmd** will disable the scroll bar, but **Windows Terminal** will let me scroll up.

Is there a way to set Windows Terminal to make it behave like other terminals.

Comment: The old console window would be _Conhost,_ not cmd.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in my WLS2 Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Windows Terminal isn't being told to switch to the alternate screen buffer when running apps like `man`, `vim`, and `less`.

From [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43204517/11810933):

> Alternate screen buffer is designed to provide exactly this functionality for full-screen terminal programs. In normal operation, output gets added to the scrollback buffer (and most terminals let the user scroll back to previous lines). Switching to the alternate screen buffer the scrollback buffer is left alone, and alternate screen buffer output is not added to the scrollback buffer. When returning from alternate screen buffer, the original scrollback buffer state is restored. This is what full-screen applications like `nano` use.

That sounds a lot like what you describe -- you can scroll back to previous lines after executing full-screen programs.

If alternate mode was being engaged, then the output of the full-screen commands would not be added to the scrollback buffer.

What does `echo $TERM` show?  If it isn't `screen-256color`, try setting it via:

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

Not that that's the ultimate solution.  It *should* be set automatically (and correctly) for you.

If `TERM` turns out to be the problem, is something in your startup scripts attempting to set it?

```
grep -r TERM .*
```

Comment: echo $TERM shows 'xterm-256color', in both Windows Terminal and conhost. export TERM=screen-256color won't fix this problem. [Lines scrolled up by less command remain to exist after quitting the command](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4676) seems to be the same issue, and not fixed yet.

Comment: @Wot You're right - that issue (and the original [#381](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/381)) look more like what you are seeing.  And given the steps in the Github issue, I can reproduce that as well.